# Ajax Request dont work without alert statement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with a `AJAX` call. I am trying to access the inputs of a `HTML`
form element and write this to a database with a `PHP` script.

My `JS` code looks like this....

```
function getWriteValues() {

    var x = document.getElementById("eingabemaske");
    var jqxhr = $.post( "source/form_handler.php", 
                         $( "#eingabemaske" ).serialize() );    

    alert( 'Eintragung erfolgreich durchlaufen' );
}
```

The PHP part isn't interesting because there nothing except the database insert happens.

Now to my Problem. The Function makes what it should do. But when I delete the ***alert()*** statement, nothing works any more. That means that nothing is written to the database and the ajax call could not be made. I can't figure out where the problem is. 
I use jQuery in Version 2.1.1.

Comment: How are you calling `getWriteValues()`?

Comment: i call it from a submit button in the form element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click the submit button you:

1. Run the JS
2. Send the Ajax HTTP request
3. Submit the form
4. Leave the current page
5. Cancel the Ajax HTTP request because there isn't going to be anything left to handle it.

Either:

- [Prevent the default action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) of the submit button so you don't leave the page *or*
- Get rid of the JS and do your database insertion in the program you specify in the `action` of the form

Answer (score 0):

Do you call getWriteValues(), if the the form is submitted?
If so, don't forget to **return false;**

Comment: In the submit onclick-line? after calling getWriteValue?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check in your html "name" attribute is defined for each form elements or not as serialize() takes element name and its value.
2. Check whether you're getting the values in getWriteValues()
3. Verify these values are passed to form_handler.php script.

sample:

```
<form id="eingabemaske">
    <input id="abc" name="abc" value="test" />
    <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#submit').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        getWriteValues();
    });
});

function getWriteValues() {

    console.log($( "#eingabemaske" ).serialize());
    var jqxhr = $.post( "form_handler.php", 
                         $( "#eingabemaske" ).serialize() );    

    //alert( 'Eintragung erfolgreich durchlaufen' );
}

</script>
```

in php script

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to that alert message is giving time to ajax to perform its work. please check all the process that happens before and after the ajax. Also, as you are calling ajax from submit button (i suppose that that u have called this function from "onsubmit" attribute of the form), may be its submtting the form before ajax is completed. Please return false at the end of function in order to stop function processing further.